# Changing siteurl and home option in Wordpress 4.4?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

When restoring a backup using [UpDraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) we used to login to the Wordpress instance and execute the following commands to change the `siteurl` and `home` options (using the wp-cli):

```
wp option update home 'https://<our dns>'
wp option update siteurl 'https://<our dns>'
```

This worked when using Wordpress 4.3 but after upgrading to 4.4 setting the `siteurl` and `home` options doesn't seem to have any effect. Has this changed in version 4.4 and if so how do I go about changing it (preferably using the wordpress cli)?

Comment: Are those options possibly declared in your wp-config and overriding the wp-cli commands?

Comment: @ColinMarshall Thanks for the tip but they are not declared in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your WP CLI client. [From their blog](http://wp-cli.org/blog/versions-0.21.1-and-0.20.4.html):

> Importantly, due to the nature of these changes, WP-CLI versions prior
>   to 0.20.4 will be incompatible with WordPress 4.4.

It's not that the `home` and `siteurl` options changed, it's about how WP CLI is working and how it include files to build his own *wp-settings.php*. Considering there have been a lot of file adds in the last version, WP CLI need to be updated to work with this new files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the "wp --info" says that I already have WP-CLI version 0.21.1 installed.

Comment: That's weird. Could you try to run `wp option update home 'https://<our dns>' --debug` to see if any error comes up?